# How to cycle through a block of code and operate on non-contiguous columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have researched this issue on several different sites with no clear way to do what I want:

I have a spreadsheet with 68 pairs of columns from 'B' to 'EG' and one leading column of data in 'A'.
I want create a new worksheet and name it for the header for the first column of each pair of columns, then copy the column of data in 'A' and the pair of columns into the new worksheet, and do the same for each succeeding pair of columns.  I can create the new worksheets from the existing spreadsheet data, but not sure how to name the new worksheets to match the header field.

The following code will create a new worksheet and copy the data, but it won't name the worksheet, and I have to create 68 separate blocks for each succeeding pair of columns! Can anyone suggest a mod to the code to loop through the columns and do what I want?  Generated code is below! And any real help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks Mike

Code:

```
Sub testcopy()

 testcopy Macro

 Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+f

    Range("A5:A17,B5:B17,C5:C17").Select
    Range("C5").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    Range("A5:A17,D5:D17,E5:E17").Select
    Range("E5").Activate
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    Range("A5").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
.
.
.
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you familiar with writing `for` loops in VBA? 
Also, to name a new worksheet you'll want `sheets.add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).name = "worksheetname"`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Sub testcopy()

Dim shtSrc As Worksheet, sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, rngA As Range, rngTwo As Range

Set rngA = ActiveSheet.Range("A5:A17")
Set rngTwo = ActiveSheet.Range("B5:C17")

    For i = 1 To 68

        Set sht = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        sht.Name = rngTwo.Cells(1).Value

        Application.Union(rngA, rngTwo).Copy
        sht.Range("A5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Set rngTwo = rngTwo.Offset(0, 2)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thank you very much! This works perfectly and does exactly what I wanted to do!!! One more question - how can I best learn how to do this Excel macro/vba coding?

Comment: I prefer a book when beginning something: I started with the XL95 equivalaent of this one: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/book/excel_2010_power_programming_with_vba/

Comment: Hi Tim, You Rock!!! I used your code and added a few lines to create charts on each new worksheet the code created, and everything worked beautifully!!! I will get the book and hopefully learn to do this magical stuff!!!  Thank you for the help and the advice about the book!